# Excel VBA Copy/Paste without clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

Struggling to resolve this error, when trying to copy a range of column to a new range.  I had this code working but crashed and can't figure it out the second time.

Sheets("destination").Columns("A:E").Value = Sheets("source").Columns("A:E").Value

Comment: What is the error you get? How do you run this code? Your object references are not fully specified. The size of data to copy may be too much.

Comment: Thank you.   I was able to figure it out and it was a dumb error: I had very subtle typo in the source name.